# Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'

Tags: reactjs, http-headers, hosting, github-pages

I have just started react.

My page works fine on localhost.

Now I am trying to host my page on github.

I have used "npm run deploy" and hosted

This is my package.json

[image: This is my package.json]

Now when I am trying to access my page I run into errors and the first warning concerns me the most .

[image: Errors]

This is my page : [Github Page](https://danjaved.github.io/To_Do_React_App/)

What is this "Permission Policy" and how do I fix it?

Comment: Your gh-pages is  404. have u fixed it? how？

Comment: No, I ignored them. 
But here are the threads that can help. 

https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1506

https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1263

Comment: Is it open source? Let me read and I can better help you ;-) 
My gh is @renatoexpert

Answer (score 34):

Basically you can ignore it. GitHub hosted pages disable FLoC, which is Google's 3rd party cookie alternative. GitHub, Microsoft, doesn't seems to like it.

https://github.blog/changelog/2021-04-27-github-pages-permissions-policy-interest-cohort-header-added-to-all-pages-sites/

Comment: Google decided to kill FLoC, replacing with Topics API.
https://blog.google/products/chrome/get-know-new-topics-api-privacy-sandbox/

Comment: Can you answer the question first? How to fix this?

Comment: Is there a better answer than "ignore it?"

Comment: Please is there an alternate to just ignoring it.

Answer (score 10):

I know it is a little bit late. But I'll keep this here as I don't see an answer on how to fix this problem.
So we basically just need to add this `<meta>` tag on `index.html` file:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Permissions-Policy" content="interest-cohort=()">
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76316947/1066234

Comment: This doesn't get rid of the error/warning.

Answer (score 3):

No one actually addressed the other errors in the responses. The problem is that your links to the CSS and JS files are wrong.

It is something like (if you inspect the network) or check the index.html file.

```
https://USERNAME.github.io/assets/index-97b0971f.css
```

and it should have the **repository** name on it. Therefore the correct link should be:

```
https://USERNAME.github.io/REPOSITORY/assets/index-97b0971f.css
```

If you are using some "frontend tooling" like `Vite.js` you should go to the `vite.config.js` and add the property `base` like the example below:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/tweak/",
 //...whatever you had here remains the same
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue use "exact" word with routes in app.js
then deploy it.

have a look your path will be change so you can also change your path of your home route to exact /mvp in my case...

[image]

```
  return <BrowserRouter>
<div className="App">
<Routes>
     
    <Route exact path="/" element={ <Home /> } />
    <Route exact path="startcreating" element={ <Start /> } />
    <Route exact path="aboutus" element={ <About /> } />
    {/* <Route path="signup" element={ <SignUpModel /> } /> */}
</Routes> 
</div>
</BrowserRouter>;
```

Answer (score 0):

**basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}** 
add this attribute to BrowserRouter in the index.js file.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).