# why i cannot see my projet online with github

Tags: reactjs, github, build, package.json

i have built React app in github, but i couldn't see it online, the page is empty.
When i opened the browser console, i have this :

**warning** :

```
Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'.
```

**error 1** :

```
GET https://meriemu.github.io/TestCaseLvmh/data.json 404
```

**error 2** :

```
 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

**Error 3 :**

```
GET https://meriemu.github.io/TestCaseLvmh/favicon.ico 404
```

Here is the github link : https://github.com/Meriemu/TestCaseLvmh

And this is my page : https://meriemu.github.io/TestCaseLvmh/

**Here a screenshot of my repo :**

[image]

And the browser console :
[image]
**My package.json :**

```
{
      "homepage": "https://Meriemu.github.io/TestCaseLvmh",
      "name": "test-case-lvmh",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "classnames": "^2.3.2",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "sass": "^1.55.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
      },
    ...
    ..
    ...
    .
```

Comment: This might answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/69619035/11877521

Comment: didn't helped me, i can't find an answer, i think the problem come first from `data.json` location but i don't know how