# application cannot be run on localhost or with github page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

Can I ask for help? Initially, the application that I built using React JS could run on localhost. However, when I try to deploy using GitHub pages, the application cannot be run even though the React code has been deployed to GitHub.

This is the json package that I set to deploy with GitHub pages

```
{
  "name": "movie-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "http://xcage88.github.io/movie-app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "gh-pages": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0"
  }
}
```

this is code index and app.js

`App.js` :

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignUp from './component/SignUp';
import ForgotForm from './component/ForgotForm';
import LoginForm from './component/LoginForm';
import MainPage from './component/MainPage';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' exact element={<LoginForm/>}/>
          <Route path='/forgot' element={<ForgotForm/>}/>
          <Route path='/sign-up' element={<SignUp/>}/>
          <Route path='/main/*' element={<MainPage/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './style/style.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle'
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

when I try to run it, the result is like this:

[run in GitHub pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzaRu.png)

[run in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxpSL.png)

if you want to try it, click or copy/paste the link below
[react app](http://xcage88.github.io/movie-app)

Answer (score 1):

I can't exactly tell you why *you* are getting the error from the first screenshot. It seems like it is some Google-Thingy.
I found this related question and it seems like you have to set a flag to ignore or disable this "feature". As I looked further into the topic, in your case it's more about *enabling* the feature instead of disabling.
[Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75119417/11818002)
Maybe you find more when you search for "floc google".
For your *localhost* problem, it seems like the path is just `/` instead of `/movie-app`.